# MSI with server core features checking

Tags: c#, windows-installer, server-core

I have created an MSI-package to install a WCF service and web application to Windows Server Core 2008 R2 SP1.

The installer-process needs to check if the required features to run the WCF and Web app are installed on this server, and install them only if required.

I believe that we'll need a custom action to achieve this. 
Please, could does anyone know how to check and install features programmatically?

Looking forward to hearing from you guys.

Many Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632241/how-can-i-programmatically-check-if-a-server-feature-is-installed-in-windows-serv) to check all feature already install in server core.

To install the server features, i used the Process class to call dism command.

```
Process.Start("dism.exe", "/online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ISAPIFilter");
```

With this, i could create custom action in MSI that could check and install server feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MsiGetFeatureState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370117%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [MsiSetFeatureState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370387%28VS.85%29.aspx) functions.

Please note that these functions use a MSI handle, so you cannot use an EXE or Installer Class Action. You can find a custom action tutorial here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/msicustomaction.aspx